# Lightweight automatic phpunit testing frameworks

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, automated-tests

I'm looking for a lightweight and low profile automatic testing framework for a couple php sites I'll be developing. I know of Selenium, but I've also heard it can be a bit of a resource hog (is that true?).

Comment: For unittests, PHPUnit is great. For functional testing, Selenium (with PHPUnit_Selenium component) is great. What is it exactly you want to automate? The running of the tests (i.e. Continuous Integration), of the testing of your sites (clicking through it)?

Comment: I plan on doing TDD and having a bunch of unit tests run after every git commit (or every time period) so I can see if anything fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on your comment: "*a bunch of unit tests run after every git commit (or every time period)*") [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/) is what you want. It is the de facto standard unit testing for PHP, and feature-rich.

Selenium is for browser control, and can be used for functional tests of a web site, interacting just as the user would (i.e. you specify buttons to press, and keyboard clicks). Selenium tests have much more overhead, so you should only use them for the tests that unit tests cannot do. (Your Selenium tests will also implicitly be testing your javascript, AJAX, Apache configuration, etc. so they don't have the ability to target a problem in the way a good unit test can.)

Comment: Awesome. Does PHPUnit have a web interface to view current builds and to see if its passing/failing?

Comment: There is https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit which is looking better and better (but I don't personally use it).

Comment: @MaxMackie Or look into continuous integration (phpUnderControl or Jenkins are the most popular for use with PHPUnit).